# Forget keystore path

Tags: android

I cleaned my PC days ago and know I'm realising that I don't find my keystore for the signing process of my app.

Luckily I have a complete backup of my filesystem, so is it possible to read the Android Studio config files to find the path of the keystore?
Windows search wasn't helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

the path should be in `signingConfigs` section in `app/build.gradle` file.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no section in the gradle file. I used Android Studio to create the keystore

Comment: As far as my experience goes, AS stores all build parameters in build files under project folder.

Comment: I found it! It was in %USERPROFILE%\.android

Answer (score 0):

Search in your computer the file "idea.log". Search in each idea.log with ctr+f "keystore" and the code will appears.